# Hide another div if not contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys I have filter with the code:

```
$(".title").not(":contains('" + $("[name=filter]").val() + "')").hide()
```

The problem is that the div class title is in the div class sortAll. ( with many more div's)

I want it to hide the sortAll where the .title is in.

```
<div class="sortAll">
    <div class="somediv"> </div>
    <div class="sortss">
       <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: Which div exactly you want to hide on what condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I want it to hide the sortAll where the .title is in.***

You can find the `.title` element, traverse to closest `.sortAll` and hide it:

```
$(".title").closest('.sortAll').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

**I want it to hide the sortAll where the .title is in.**

this will find the last parent of `.title` and hide them::

```
$(".title").parents('div').last().hide();
```